# Execute next() after the iteration in for loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataclass reading data from some source. I made `__iter__` and `__next__` methods for this class, to be able to loop through it:

```
def __iter__(self):
    # Return to the first entry, if it is not the current one
    if self._tree.GetReadEntry() != 0:
        self._tree.GetEntry(0)

    return self

## The next() method for iteration
def __next__(self):
    current_entry = self._tree.GetReadEntry()
    # If reading an entry after the last, raise an exception
    if current_entry == self._tree.GetEntries() - 1:
        raise StopIteration

    # Read the next entry
    self._tree.GetEntry(current_entry + 1)

    # Return self, as all values are accessed through self
    return self
```

The problem is that the for-loop calls `next()` at the very beginning. So I start with reading entry 1 from the source, instead of entry 0. I know I can set some variables to check if it is the first iteration, and in such a case get entry 0, and if not, get the next entry, but I wonder if there is a more proper way to do it inside the class, without modifying a loop to call `next()` manually, etc.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the rest of the methods ?

Comment: You've misimplemented `__iter__`; if you class is an itera*tor* it should do *nothing* but `return self`; if it's a (non-iterator) itera*ble* it should return a brand-new object (the new itera*tor*). Your code is [violating the contract for non-iterator iterables and iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64577138/364696) (trying to do bits of both in one class). The `for` loop isn't calling `next()`. It's implicitly invoking `__iter__` before looping begins, and your `__iter__` is *broken*.

Comment: I realise that I do some extra stuff instead of just returning `self` in `__iter__`. However, that does not influence my problem. Even if I modify the `__iter__`, the for loop still would skip entry 0.

Comment: I assume you mean methods used in this example. These are not my methods but CERN ROOT TTree's methods. `GetEntry(x)` reads element x from the source (a TTree), `GetReadEntry()` gets the entry currently loaded into memory and `GetEntries()` gets the number of all the entries in the source.

Comment: Changing the class from iterator to iterable works. However, according to the linked StackOverflow answer, I should return another class, and I am yielding self (not sure how to add a big block of code to a comment here...). I wonder if it is incorrect in some way.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve it is to change the class from iterator to iterable, as suggested in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64577138/364696). This way the first value that a for loop gets is the first entry from the data source. I am not aware of a way to do it with iterator.